# Remove double quotes and special characters from string list python

Tags: python, string, list, character

I'm pretty new in python.

I have a list like this:

```
['SACOL1123', "('SA1123', 'AAW38003.1')"]
['SACOL1124', "('SA1124', 'AAW38004.1')"]
```

And I want to remove the extra double quotes and paranthesis, so it looks like this:

```
['SACOL1123', 'SA1123', 'AAW38003.1']
['SACOL1124', 'SA1124', 'AAW38004.1']
```

This is what I managed to do:

```
newList = [s.replace('"(', '') for s in list]
newList = [s.replace(')"', '') for s in newList]
```

But the output is exactly like the input list. How can I do it?

Comment: You have an extra `"`

Comment: `['SACOL1123', "('SA1123', 'AAW38003.1')"]` is a list of two elements, is that intentional? I.e. you really want to massage that into a list of three elements? Or is there a typo in the input list?

Comment: I know, I'm trying to remove it...

Comment: it is not a typo, it's what i want to solve

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using `ast.literal_eval`. Your second element from list is string representation of a valid Python tuple which you can safely evaluate.

```
[[x[0]] + list(ast.literal_eval(x[1])) for x in lst]
```

**Code**:

```
import ast

lst = [['SACOL1123', "('SA1123', 'AAW38003.1')"],
       ['SACOL1124', "('SA1124', 'AAW38004.1')"]]

output = [[x[0]] + list(ast.literal_eval(x[1])) for x in lst]

# [['SACOL1123', 'SA1123', 'AAW38003.1'],
#  ['SACOL1124', 'SA1124', 'AAW38004.1']]
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what x[0] and x[1] refer to here?

Comment: First and second element of your list.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by converting each item in the list to a string and then substituting the punctuation with empty string. Hope this helps:

```
import re

List = [['SACOL1123', "('SA1123', 'AAW38003.1')"], 
        ['SACOL1124', "('SA1124', 'AAW38004.1')"]]

New_List = []
for Item in List:
    New_List.append(re.sub('[\(\)\"\'\[\]\,]', '', str(Item)).split())

New_List
Output: [['SACOL1123', 'SA1123', 'AAW38003.1'], 
         ['SACOL1124', 'SA1124', 'AAW38004.1']]
```